# React-player: Disable full-screen on mobile when starting the video

Tags: reactjs, react-player

I'm using a react-player library (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player) and everything works great, but there is one thing that I would like to adjust and would like to know how to do it. The problem is that when I play the video from a mobile phone, it goes full screen and starts playing. This is something that only on mobile happens, on computer browser, everything works fine. How can I achieve that when the video starts playing it stays in the same small space and from there I can pick the fullscreen option later?

```
<ReactPlayer
   url={'https://www.testvideo.mp4'}
   width="100%"
   height="100%"
   controls
   muted
   playing}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I doubt this has anything to do with the library if it is using HTML5 .

You can try using `playsinline` attribute of : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video